# Bibliography (not References) with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to add a bibliography section. The bibliography section will:

1. List references, as formatted by bibtex but under the header "Bibliography"
2. Not have its shorthand/number/link appear anywhere else in the document.

The best I've gotten is to forcefully change the name with:

```tex
\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}
```

Then populate references with `\nocite`.

Finally, I can then just:

```tex
\bibliography{refs}{}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

This method still assigns a key to the reference which is displayed at the very left which I don't want:

[image: Bibliography: [Agrawal2021] Agrawal, G. (2021). Fiber-Optic Communication Systems. Wiley.]

Is it possible to not have this appear?
It would also be nice to separate out references and bibliography into different sections, where references use the default behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The layout of the bibliography depends on the uses style. You could, e.g., use [package `biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with option `style=authoryear` to have a bibliography without such kind of labels. The default title depends on the used class. For example `article` uses `References`, but `report` and `book` use `Bibliography`. You can change this indeed redefining `\refname` resp. `\bibname`.  `biblatex` also provides an option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not very detailed, e.g.,

- how you want the bibliography shown,
- which class you are using.

However, it seems you don't want the result of `\bibliographystyle{apa}`. So maybe you want something like an author-year style. If so, you could, e.g., use [package `biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with option `style=authoryear`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% This is only an example, provided by
                                % biblatex and therefore useful for minimal
                                % working examples.
\nocite{*}% Show all references from the database.

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

After running LaTeX + Biber + LaTeX + LaTeX (LaTeX can be either PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX), you would get a document with six pages of bibliography. The first one:

[image]

You can get something similar using BiBTeX with `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`, but with less flexibility:

```
% Following environment is just used to generate an example bib-file.
% Ususally you would not use it in a real document.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Agrawa2021,
  author={Agrawal, G.},
  year=2021,
  title={Fiber-Optic Communication Systems},
  publisher={Wiley}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\refname{Bibliography}}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section{One test section}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

In this case you have to run LaTeX + BibTeX + LaTeX + LaTeX to get:

[image: using BibTeX]

Note: There are already a lot of questions about making bibliographies using either BibTeX and some packages like `natbib` or `apastyle`, or using `biblatex` and `biber`. For information about setting up your editor to use `biber` instead of `bibtex` see, e.g., [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/277964)

If you have further questions about making a bibliography please ask a new more detailed question and also add [a minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964).